# How to use a CSS attribute selector to target a specific height?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So basically, I want to only style the first specific box on my site.

I would like to try and use an attribute selector to target `height` (trust me, there was no other way of styling this, I literally tried everything).

I have tried the following (along with many other variations):

```
.first_child[style='height: 299px;']:first-child  {
background-color: red;
}

.clear[style='height: 299px;']:first-child  {
background-color: red;
}

.first_child:first-of-type [height='299px;'] {
background-color: red;
}
```

Although, I just can't seem to get it working.

Is this fixable, or am I attempting the impossible?

Below is a screenshot of my HTML structure if needed:

[image]

Comment: Works here, in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/U6AdX/3/

Comment: I think you are adding broken over-qualification *not* related to the attribute selector. Try with: `div[style='height: 299px;']:first-child` (that is, remove `.clear` and `.first_child` and other simple selectors which have no such matching style attribute).

Comment: Wait, Wordpress doesn't let one override the HTML it outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *= instead of just =, and make sure of exact text match. That said, it's a very bad idea. Try something else:

```
#content div.columns div.clear:first-child > div.child:first-child {}
```

Comment: Yes, horrible idea I know. But it's the only idea left basically. It's Wordpress... and everything is dynamically created upon page load. Literally tried everything in the book to try and get this working.

Comment: I updated my answer withadifferent approach after I saw the HTML.

Comment: Worked very well! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.clear:first-child .child:first-child {
   background-color: red;
}
```